# AutoCad: how to choose a font of a text in a script

Tags: fonts, autocad

I would like to write an AutoCad script that would print a text but I want to choose a specific font as well (font: txt). How could I do that? Thanks for your help!

For now I have only this:

_text 1079.0292,593.8346 99.8441 0.0 Katarzyna

Answer (score 0):

AutoCAD doesn't allow you to directly control the font of text while placing text. In the text commands, you can only choose from a currently existing Style within your DWG. Below is detailed info on the text command within AutoCAD

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-D1C664DD-63D9-467E-8EC1-2F5A1777A924-htm.html

What you can do, however; is run the -style command with a script, automate the creation of a style with the font you want and then have the text routine in your script reference that style.

Here is an example of that.  You can copy/paste this directly into the AutoCAD command line and see it in action

```
-style TESTSTYLE 
Arial
6 1 0 N N
-text S
TESTSTYLE
16,20
0.0
BLAH
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using _text, so set the font is complicated. but maybe You may use Mtext? If so You can easy set font for example like this:

```
_-Mtext 1070.0,590.0 1080.0,595.0 {\fTahoma.ttf|;Katarzyna}
```